# I'm new one in Android and HELP :)

Tags: android

I'd started for about a mouth and I have some problems now  :(

1.
I create a TabActivity and it has three Activity(tab1,tab2,tab3).I wanna realize that if I press a button in tab1,then TextView in tab2 can be changed. I've tried Intent and Bundle , but that didn't work and force close  . Maybe because of the TabActivity I think .

2.
If I have a layout and there are many TextView on it. But some are out of the screen. How can I scroll the screen?

3.
Is it possible that TextView in Tablelayout can be clicked ?

I've sreached there problems on Google for there days but still bother me . Really need help, Thanks  :)

Comment: As these three questions have nothing to do with each other, they really should be posted as three separate questions.  That way if someone only knows the answer to one they can answer that.

Comment: Also, it allows you to post a meaningful subject, which is likely to attract more views than "HELP".

Comment: I see.Sorry for that.I'm new one here and come from Taiwan so my English may be not so good. I'll remember that and thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Switch to having `Views` in your tabs instead of `Activities`, and inter-tab communication becomes much simpler.
2. Put things in a `ScrollView`.
3. Yes. Just call `setOnClickListener()`. It will not have any visual cue to suggest it can be clicked, nor will it visibly react when clicked. Usually, one uses a `Button` for things designed for users to click.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). But I've tried to put all TextView in a ScrollView and it force close.

Comment: @Kooper: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to look at the Java stack trace associated with your error.